# Retrieving submitted "Answers"? Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, controller

I have an app with the following tables:
Courses,
Exercises,
Answers, and
Users (with Devise).

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :exercise
belongs_to :user
end
```

Each exercise has an html answer box and a "submit" button, but I want to know if the data submitted  by users through the answers in each exercise goes somewhere or what can I do to retrieve it?

What would I need to do to have the answers saved somewhere where they can reviewed, or even maybe sent by email?

I know like html forms that are sent by email when you hit submit, but would that indicate which user submitted the answer?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current scenario you must have `exercise_id` and `user_id` column in your answers table.

When you submit a form for answer you must have `exercise_id` present. And you will easily get that from controller while you are showing exercise to answer.

Now for user_id, If you are using devise than you are getting current_user object every where in your application after login.

So to save answer you must write something like this:

```
current_user.answers.create(params_answer)
```

And params_answer should be something like:

```
def params_answer
  params.require(:answer).permit(:exercise_id, :answer_text, :xxxx, :yyyy)
end
```

To get answer of any qustion that current user submitted:

```
curren_user.answers
```

To get answers of perticular exercise

```
curren_user.answers.where(:exercise_id, '##')
```

For more info go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand your words clearly.
Using `session` may help.